# Type mismatch with function

Tags: haskell

I made the following code:

```
formateaAux2::[String] -> [String]
formateaAux2 xs = map (++ " ") xs

formateaAux1::[String] -> Int -> [String]
formateaAux1 xs n 
            |n > 0 = do 
                       x <- (formateaAux2(take n xs)) ++ (drop (length(xs) - n) xs)
                       formateaAux1 x (n - length(xs)) -- where it errors
            |n <= 0 = []
formateaAux1 [] _ = []
```

The purpose of these functions is the following:

- formateaAux2 takes a list of strings and adds a blank space `" "` to each element in it. (works OK)
- formateaAux1 is supposed to take a list of strings and a number, and use formateaAux2 on n words. If n is greater than the number of words in the list, it'll repeat the same process until n = 0.

Imagine the list of strings is ["Hello", "World"] and n is 4, the objective would be to have as output ["Hello  ", "World  "], with two blank spaces after each word. If n were 3, then only "Hello" would have two spaces after it, "World" only have one.

So far so good, but I'm getting the following type error telling me that in `formateaAux1 x (n - length(xs))`, the code expects x to be of type [String] and yet it only gets String. However x should be of type [String] since I'm concatenating a list made from `formateaAux2` (which returns [String]) and the higher order function `drop`, right?

Been at this for a while and I don't know where to look at anymore (though it's probably something trivial), any help is appreciated!

Comment: What do you want for `formateaAux1 ["a","b","c","d","e"] 17`? I’m guessing you would want the result to be `["a    ","b    ","c   ","d   ","e   "]`, but some confirmation would be nice.

Comment: @bradrn Yep, that'd be the expected output

Comment: Use `let x = ... in ...`, not `do x <- ...` -- you are not working with monads here. In your code `x <- list` means "take any one element of `list`" instead of "take the whole list".

Comment: @chi Understood, forgot about that. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to what @chi said:

```
formateaAux2::[String] -> [String]
formateaAux2 xs = map (++ " ") xs


formateaAux1::[String] -> Int -> [String]
formateaAux1 xs n 
            |n > 0 = let x = (formateaAux2(take n xs)) ++ (drop n xs) in
                       formateaAux1 x (n - length(xs))
            |n <= 0 = xs
formateaAux1 [] _ = []
```